# What does the setting "Autoformat visible SQL" do?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer version 4.0.1.14, there's a setting named "Autoformat visible SQL" but I can't figure out what it does, or whether it's broken.
[image]

According to the built-in `F1` help, it should format my code while I type it:

> **Autoformat PL/SQL in Procedures, Packages, Views, and Triggers:** If this option is checked, the SQL Formatter options are applied automatically as you enter and modify PL/SQL code in procedures, packages, views, and triggers; if this option is not checked, the SQL Formatter options are applied only when you so request.

The help heading is slightly different than the screenshot, but there is no other occurrence of "autoformat" anywhere in Help.

Comment: Does this only apply when you're editing an existing stored code (e.g. a procedure opened from the connections pane), rather then in an SQL Worksheet, perhaps? [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#CHDCAGJI) kind of hints at that but it's not clear.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've just tried editing a _package_ but it didn't work in there either. What's more, the autocomplete dropdown shows the tables and attributes in uppercase, and these are also inserted as uppercase, _and the autoformatter doesn't change them to lowercase_ even though the rules specify that setting. I am getting the feeling SQL Developer is simply not that polished.

Comment: You're not the first to suggest that *8-) Probably worth clarifying which version you're using though. You might get a better answer [on the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)).

Comment: Version 4.0.1.14 -- I added that above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4.2 this option is available under "Code Editor" -> "Format". It's still available in Version 20.2.

This option has no affect on the worksheet nor on the PL/SQL editor. AFAIK it only affects the "SQL" tab for database objects that are opened e.g. via the "Connections" window. For example tables, views, triggers. For these objects, the code is read from the database and then automatically formatted according to your formatting settings, if the option "Auto formatting of visible SQL and PL/SQL" is checked.

This SQL tab is read-only and the formatter cannot be invoked there. Therefore I consider the help text wrong or at least misleading.